# Configuring a connectionSignUp with social:jdbc-connection-repository element in spring social

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-social

I'm using spring social with XML configuration and I would like to inject the property connectionSignUp to enable implicit signup, but that's not possible because that element
social:jdbc-connection-repository does not expect that parameter.

I'm trying to modify one of the samples, namely this one:
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-sec-xml

The social:jdbc-connection-repository element is in the file:
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/blob/master/spring-social-showcase-sec-xml/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/social.xml

Thanks for any help or a workaround!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You caught something that was overlooked in the new configuration support. I recognize that this doesn't help you solve your problem today, but I'm glad that you found it so that now it can be fixed. That's precisely why we do milestone releases.

I'll be sure to work it into the M3 release (I'm shooting for the end of Feb or very early March). But just to remind me, could you open an improvement issue at https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SOCIAL to track this? And be sure to include a link to this SO question as a reference URL so that I'll know to come back and update this answer when I have the fix in a snapshot build. Thanks

In the meantime, there's not a lot of convenient workarounds. You could go back to declaring the connection repositories explicitly. Or you *could* have post processor bean (either BeanPostProcessor or BeanFactoryPostProcessor implementation) that sets that property. Actually, thinking it through, the post-processor workaround is probably the easiest for a temporary solution.

Comment: I went ahead and created the improvement issue (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SOCIAL-352) and you should see the new attribute in the latest 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT build.

Answer (score 0):

i have used the  in an effort to SocialAuthenticationFilter, seems its not recognized by spring. as its complanied userConnectionRepository not not defind. i am using maven 1.1.0.M4

```
<bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="userIdSource"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="userConnectionRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg index="3" ref="connectionFactoryLocator"/>

    <!-- Sets the url of the registration form. -->
    <property name="signupUrl" value="/user/register"/>
</bean>
```

further can i know full xml configuration of defining  userConnectionRepository and connectionFactoryLocator without using `<social:jdbc-connection-repository/>`

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is not very clear at all. I cannot understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: hmm .. this isn't an answer but a question? If so, please post a ... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)